# Error appearing in bash script when run with LaunchControl

Tags: ruby, macos, bash, applescript, rvm

I have the following script

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
Dir.chdir('/Users/Chris/Sites/mentor') do
  audit = `/Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@mentor/bin/bundle-audit`
  system(%(osascript -e 'display notification "#{audit}" with title "bundle-audit"'))
end
```

When I run it from my local folder it gives a notification like

```
bundle-audit
No vulnerabilities found
```

However, when the same script is being run periodically by LaunchControl, the notification is just

```
bundle-audit
```

The stderr output is

```
env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: That's an error, not "output being lost". Regarding your problem: you need to source RVM init script.

Comment: I have tried putting ```source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm``` in the script but does not work. How do I ```source RVM init script``` on Mac Osx 10.11.1?

Comment: Please include in the question how exactly you are putting `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` in your script. That matters a lot.

Comment: I am now following the approach advocated here, http://notes.jerzygangi.com/creating-a-ruby-launchd-task-with-rvm-in-os-x/. But even this is not working completely, so I am going to ask a more general question on superuser and then come back here with what I hope is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to solve this is to use the tutorial set out [here](http://notes.jerzygangi.com/creating-a-ruby-launchd-task-with-rvm-in-os-x/). I have summarised the approach below. The summary includes a fix for a problem that occurred when I followed the tutorial.

My ruby task is called `daily_checks.rb` and is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
Dir.chdir('/Users/Chris/Documents/Sites/mentor') do
  audit = `bundle-audit`
  system(%(osascript -e 'display notification "#{audit}" with title "bundle-audit"'))
end
```

Set up an RVM alias and a bash file at `/usr/local/bin/regular_checks.sh` that contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/wrappers/regular_checks/ruby /Users/Chris/Documents/Sites/mentor/script/daily_checks.rb
```

Note the above differs from the tutorial due to the addition of the `#!/bin/bash` line.

When this is done, then launchControl runs the bundle-audit command successfully.